# In git, transfer commits from one remote to another remote with another author

Tags: git, shell

In git, we are working in a bitbucket repository with our personal accounts, but we want to transfer automatically from one bitbucket account to another bitbucket account changing all authors to another one (ex: John Doe) when  a commit is done.

```
| Remote A |           | Remote B |

Commit 1: Mike         Commit 1: John Doe
Commit 2: James        Commit 2: John Doe
Commit 3: James        Commit 3: John Doe
Commit 4: Mike         Commit 4: John Doe
Commit 5: Lara         Commit 5: John Doe
```

For now we have accomplished it, but only works the first time, we can't transfer the next commits:

```
git clone --bare git@repo .
git fetch origin

git filter-branch -f --commit-filter 'export GIT_AUTHOR_NAME="John Doe"; export GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL="johndoe@example.com"; export GIT_COMMITTER_NAME="John Doe"; export GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL="johndoe@example.com"; git commit-tree "$@"' -- --all

git push --force --tags another_origin 'refs/heads/*'
```

Comment: I have to ask: why? There's probably an easier way to do this if we knew what you're trying to accomplish with this.

Comment: @Schwern that's a good question. The real repository is for a client (A) of a client (B) and he mustn't see the real team that is working in the project, for that client of a client we only have 1 email and we want that our team work with the same bitbucket account that are using now, we can't change the commit account every time we have this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### You cannot change a commit

Commits—in fact all Git objects—are literally immutable.  The reason is that the *name* of the object is its hash ID.  (Any other name, such as a branch or tag name pointing to a commit, is merely an alias for the "true" hash name.  The actual commit is found by hash ID, and the short, human-readable name is used to find the true name.)

What this means is that `git filter-branch` *copies* commits.  In fact, every Git command that seems to change commits, actually copies instead.  Thus, `git commit --amend` and `git rebase` also work by copying commits.  The new copies are made by taking the original commit—found, as usual, via its true name—and constructing a new commit with whatever differences are required.  If the new commit is bit-for-bit identical to the old commit, it winds up with the *same* true name, i.e., it literally is the old commit; but if anything—such as the author—is changed in any way, the new commit is different, and therefore has a different name.

#### Filter-branch therefore copies, then re-maps

As we just saw, this means `filter-branch` actually *copies* every commit it filters.  The commits it filters (copies) are the ones you ask it to, e.g., `--all` means "every commit reachable from every reference" (including tag references).  It copies commits by—at least virtually—extracting their contents into a temporary tree and their metadata (author, committer, email addresses and timestamps, and commit message) into temporary storage, applying all the specified filters to the tree and metadata, and making (or skipping) the new commit using the modified data-and-metadata.  Then it updates a mapping-file so that it knows the *new* name for each filtered old-name.

(This process is very slow, so if possible, `filter-branch` skips most of it.  If you use just index, environment, parent, message, and/or commit filters, `filter-branch` can avoid the "extract" step and do all the work with the index.  In your case, since you're not even touching the index, you could make this go even faster.)

#### The mapping is crucial, but filter-branch throws it away ... sort of

Once all commits have been filtered, the `filter-branch` command runs its last step(s):

- If there are annotated tags pointing to filtered commits, and you have specified a `--tag-name-filter`, it copies the *annotated tag* objects too, mapping them as needed.  Because tags are intended for different purposes than branches, it does something a bit different with the tag names (which is why this is a tag *name* filter, and not a tag filter): it can make the new tags use different names.  Using `cat` as a tag name filter retains the original name.
- Then, for each "positive reference" given on the command line, `filter-branch` updates that reference to point to the new (mapped) commit instead of the (old, pre-copy operation) commit.  Of course if the filter did nothing—and assuming you did not skip any commits either—the new commit *is* the old commit and this makes no change; but if the filter did something, the new commit is different and hence this makes the *name* find the new tip commit of the new branch.  (For annotated tags, they were already handled by the tag name filter.  For lightweight tags, they are handled the same way as branches.)

Last, `filter-branch` command *throws away the map*.

This is probably a mistake.  Among other things, it means that if you had commit notes, those notes are now attached only to the original (pre-copying) commits, not the new ones.  If `filter-branch` kept the map, you could use `git notes copy` to make them point to the new commits too.

Note that `filter-branch` *leaves all the old commits in place*.  You can find those commits using the `refs/original/` name-space: `filter-branch` copies all the existing `refs/` references into `refs/original/` before it begins its commit-copying.  This has a few side effects, of at least academic / theoretical interest: it means we can *re-compute* the mapping from old to new as long as we can re-create any "skipping" from a complex commit-filter (and as long as it's deterministic, we of course *can* do that).

In your particular case, though, you skip no commits, so this becomes easier: there's a one-to-one mapping available for all the "interesting" commits, through the `refs/original/` name-space.  I'll also assume for simplicity that you have no notes, or intend to abandon them in the (exported version of the) filtered repository.

#### How to get what you want

I don't have time to describe this in full detail, or write code to do it, but it's pretty obvious once you understand all of the above.  You must stop using `--all` and instead use `--branches` and maybe `--tags` (and decide whether you need a `--tag-name-filter` as well; this will depend on whether and how you use tags).  You may want to write your own customized script instead of using `git filter-branch` (which *is* a script, so it is easy to copy and customize).

Your original repository—the one you describe as "remote A" above—has all the original commits with all their original names.  Your desired repository, "remote B", should have all (and only) the mapped commits, with their new names.  But you would like to be able to update "remote B" now and then, while still working with "remote A".  This means you must retain, somewhere, an intermediate working repository.  Let's call this repository *F*, for filter, and refer to the other two—the two external, remote repositories—as *A* and *B*.

Inside repository *F* you will have all the original commits from some earlier snapshot of *A*, *and* all the filtered-so-far commits you have delivered to *B*.  You can rename `refs/original/refs/heads` and `refs/original/refs/tags` to `refs/saved/heads` and `refs/saved/tags`, and discard any remaining "original" references (there really should be no such references anyway).  These are commits that have *already been copied*.  Their copies have already been pushed to *B*, as well.

Now you want to pick up any *new* commits from *A*.  This step is trivial: just run `git fetch`.  For convenience, assuming no "rewinds" and slow non-customized full re-filtering with plain old `git filter-branch`, you can even fetch directly from *A*'s `refs/heads/*` into *F*'s `refs/heads/*`, and likewise for *A*'s `refs/tags/*`.  For the customized solution, fetch into an intermediate name-space such as `refs/todo/`, i.e., `refs/todo/heads/` and `refs/todo/tags`.  (To handle rewinds with the customized solution, calculate the rewinds and apply them to the filtered copies; and this will cause you to require a force push later.  This will be a little bit tricky, so I will just ignore the problem.)

Now you merely need to filter all the *new* commits.  If using `git filter-branch` and fetching directly into `refs/heads/` and `refs/tags/`, you would just need to use `--branches --tags` as the arguments for "what to filter".  This will re-filter all the filtered commits again.  We rely on the fact that re-filtering original commit *H<sub>orig</sub>* with the *same filter* as before produces a new copy *H<sub>copy</sub>* with the *same copied ID* as before, so that the new copies in repository *F* append to the existing filtered repository.

(Because that's so slow—and because you aren't changing trees—a customized filter-branch would be advisable here, but that would require much more work on my part.  Note that the commits to filter will then come from `git rev-list $(git for-each-ref --format='%(refname)' refs/todo --not $(git for-each-ref --format='%(refname)' refs/saved)` .  Get these in appropriate topological order, and append to the existing filtered chains whose tips are in the regular `refs/heads/` and `refs/tags` name-spaces.  You can figure out the "append" automatically by initializing the mappings with `refs/saved/heads/*` to `refs/heads/*`, plus `refs/saved/tags/*` to `refs/tags/*`.  This is where the rewinds get tricky.)

Once the filtering finishes and your `refs/heads/*` and `refs/tags/*` names are updated, you have all the newly filtered commits ready to push.  You need only update the `refs/saved/*` names according to the names now in `refs/original/refs/*` and then push from *F* to *B* as usual (with force if and only if there were rewinds).

#### Caveat

This all assumes that repository *B* never has any commits added to it independent of commits first sent through *A*.  If that's *not* the case—if you need some sort of bidirectional mapping—this gets much harder.